# Cuda: Where do the built-in variables reside? (threadIdx, blockIdx, blockDim, gridDim, warpSize)

Tags: cuda

I'm wondering where this information comes from.  When accessing these vars, am I really accessing a register, or somewhere else?  (My guess is that these are register values.)
I wonder if there is any speed benefit to storing them in a register?

```
__global__ void myKernel(int, float, int*) {
   const int reg1= threadIdx.y      // gonna use/Rd reg1 some 50 different places
   :  
   :  
}
```

or would it be just as fast to read threadIdx.y some 50 different times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in variables reside in different locations on different compute capabilities. On more recent devices the information is packed into special purpose registers. In the assembly (cuobjdump -sass) the instruction S2R is used to move the value from a special register to general register. The act of assigning the value to an auto variable does not require the compiler to assign the value to a register for any period of time. The compiler is likely doing the optimal assignment to a register for built-ins.

Comment: Some info on how fast the process happens would help.

Comment: The performance is dependent on the SM version, instruction scheduling, warp scheduling, and instruction mix. The best way to determine performance would be to write a micro-benchmark using one of the open source assemblers.